# Grouping separate buttons and prevent line breaks

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have some hidden buttons with vertical grouping:

```
<div id="btGrp">

<input type="button" value="Action_A" class="class_a" /><br>
<input type="button" value="Action_B" class="class_a" /><br>
<input type="button" value="Action_C" class="class_a" /><br>
<input type="button" value="Action_D" class="class_a" /><br>
<input type="button" value="Action_E" class="class_a" /><br>
<input type="button" value="Action_F" class="class_a" /><br>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#btGrp{
float: right;
height: auto;
width: 190;
margin: 55px 20px 0 0;
border: 1px solid orange;
}

.class_a{
display:none;
}
```

When some action are performed, then the corresponding button appears: Example:

[image]

And I would like to have:

[image]

Here is a JSFiddle that try to express the question:
http://jsfiddle.net/CW2Z7/25/

Comment: is br causing the space issue? if so why don't you just make br display none or remove them

Comment: Why use <br> when you could set a width of 100% for each button and have them display block when not display: none?

Comment: I would like the buttons keep the "column" effect

Comment: I don't get what exactly you're trying to do @Zamboo http://jsfiddle.net/CW2Z7/ - here it seems to look fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line breaks and update your CSS to:

```
#btGrp {
    float: right;
    height: auto;
    width: 190px; // note the addition of 'px'
    margin: 55px 20px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}

.class_a {
    display: none;
    min-width: 150px // adjust to suit
}
```

If the large gaps are still there, check the computed `line-height` and `margin` CSS for `.class_a`.

Comment: I tested it in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CW2Z7/23/ - Sorry not workin...

Comment: Finally you right: Your answer was the good one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the HTML a bit:

```
<div id="btGrp">    
<input type="button" value="Action_A" class="class_a" /><br/>
    <div><input type="button" value="Action_B" class="class_a" /></div>
    <div><input type="button" value="Action_C" class="class_a" /></div>
    <div><input type="button" value="Action_D" class="class_a" /></div>
    <div><input type="button" value="Action_E" class="class_a" /></div>
    <div><input type="button" value="Action_F" class="class_a" /></div>
</div>

<div>
<input type="button" value="Display A, C, E" id="a" /><br/>
</div>
```

Then you don't have to set the width of the button and each one of them is in the single line and you don't use the nasty `<br/>`

http://jsfiddle.net/CW2Z7/42/